# Retrieve rows which meets a certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to start by explaining what my query should do.

At my store,we sell products A,B,C and D(Product ID)
Let's say I am interested in only those transactions where Item A was sold

This is how i wrote my query

```
Select [Transaction_No],[Product ID]
from [MystoreDB$Transaction lines] 
where Date = '01-Jan-2016'
and (Product ID) = 'A'
```

The query executes without any errors,and I get the results only filtered to Product ID A.

But if I really look into the filtered transactions, I can see that there were other products bought in the same transaction(Product B was bought as well)

But the query only filtered 'the rows' with Product A

For Instance
There were total of 4 transactions done on 1-Jan-2016

Transaction 1 had
Product A + B

Transaction 2 had
Product A only

Transaction 3 had
Product A + C

Transaction 4 had
Product A only

At the end I want my query to retrieve only 2 transactions
Which is Transaction 2 and 4(since only product A was purchased)
I will ignore Transactions 1 and 3 since another product was purchased along with product A

What I want to find out is all transactions that had only Product A.
This means, the customer only bought product A and no other products.
Not sure how to get this.

I am using MYSQL for the DB engine

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `[]` around names, it uses backticks. Square brackets are for SQL-Server.

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Transaction_No
FROM
    Transactions
WHERE
    Date = '01-Jan-2016'
GROUP BY
    Transaction_No
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Product_Id = 'A' THEN Product_Id END) = COUNT(*)
```

Doing a group by with conditional aggregation will give you the desired result and as there are no sub selects etc it should preform faster than a NOT EXISTS solution.

Edit Per Your Comment:

To test to see if a customer bought both Product A & B but no other products you would have to add a couple of additional constraints in your HAVING clause.  Test that COUNT of A > 0 and COUNT of B > 0 and then that the COUNT of A & B is the same as the COUNT of All Products.

```
SELECT
    Transaction_No
FROM
    Transactions
WHERE
    Date = '01-Jan-2016'
GROUP BY
    Transaction_No
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Product_Id = 'A' THEN Product_Id END) > 0
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Product_Id = 'B' THEN Product_Id END) > 0
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Product_Id IN ('A','B') THEN Product_Id END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt,The query executed super fast.Thanks a ton.In the future if I decide to add Product B along with A to my query(A+B matchcase) then my query should be something along the lines of COUNT(CASE WHEN Product_Id = 'A' or 'B' THEN Product_ID End)....?

Comment: @Sequel that will get a little more complicated and I think you need to expand on your desire for me to answer correctly because if you say product_id A or B that would mean it would give you transactions that could be all a, all B or A & B is that what you would want?

Comment: Sorry Matt,I meant only filter transactions that have product_ids A and B(not A alone,or not B alone,but a combination of A+B)

Comment: @Sequel3 see my edit, if my answer has helped you please accept and upvote so that other's know you have gotten what you need.  cheers

Comment: Matt,you answered both my questions with ease.Great help! I am marking your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `WHERE` clause:L

```
AND [Transaction_No] NOT IN (
    SELECT [Transaction_No]
    FROM [MystoreDB$Transaction lines]
    where [Product ID] <> 'A'
)
```

to exclude customers who bought some other product.

Comment: Sorry,I added this to my where clause and the query still returned customer ID's that had products with A and C

Comment: Did they have products with A and C on the same date 01-Jan-2016? If the restriction isn't supposed to include the date, remove that from the subquery.

Comment: I misread the question, I thought you wanted to exclude *customers* who bought other products, not transactions that have other products. I've edited the answer.